# Understanding value calling in python dictionary

Tags: python

I am reading through 'Programming Python' and I have the following code:

```
bob = {'name':'Bob Smith', 'age':42, 'pay':30000, 'job':'dev'}

for (key, record) in [('bob', bob)]:
    print(record)
```

And this prints out:

```
{'name':'Bob Smith', 'age':42, 'pay':30000, 'job':'dev'}
```

My confusion is that it looks to me like it is doing the same thing as this:

```
for record in bob:
    print(record)
```

But the above code prints out the keys and not values.

So my question is, what is the difference between the two for loops that causes them to print both keys and values or just keys?

Comment: the first one is equivalent to `print(bob)`

Comment: ya, here tuple unpacking happens. `(key, record)` refers each list item. So the string `bob` should be the key and the dict  `bob` should be the value.

Comment: Why do you think the first one is "doing the same thing as" the second?  The first one is iterating over `[('bob', bob)]`, and you have nothing like that in the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `for (key, record) in [('bob', bob)]`, you are not iterating over `bob`.  You are iterating over `[('bob', bob)]` , which is a list with one element.  That element is a tuple of two things, the string `'bob'` and the object `bob` (which is a dictionary).  Your loop assigns the first one to `key` and the second to `record`.  But you don't do anything with `key` and just print `record`, so you print the dictionary.

In `for record in bob` you iterate over `bob`, which is a dictionary.  Iterating over a dictionary gives you its keys, so you get its keys.

Comment: Thanks that clarified it.